# Returning values calculated as an AJAX object is loaded

Tags: json, ajax, leaflet

I'm asynchronously loading a JSON file using LEAFLET.JS's plugin (https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax). Once the JSON file is loaded, I want to return some simple stats on the data.

In fact, I'm trying to adapt this example : https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ to make it work with AJAX. Here' s the result from the example : https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html.

I'm doing it like this:

```
var max = 0;
var min = Infinity;
function onEach(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.myVar < min) {
        min = feature.myVar;
    };
    if (feature.myVar > max) {
        max = feature.myVar;
    };
    return min, max;
}

var myObject = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('anObjectOnTheServer.json', {onEachFeature: onEach});
console.log(min, max);
```

My problem is that I cannot find the way to retrieve min and max once they are calculated.

Comment: Why you are returning the min & max? remove the line and take it another shot.

Comment: There's no mechanism to return values from the `onEachFeature` function. But since you're updating global variables in the function, it doesn't look like you need to - they will get updated as the JSON gets parsed.